# Load and move different images with the keyboard arrows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

What I would like to to do is the following:

1. When I press the left arrow only marioleft is drawn.
2. When the right arrow is pressed it only draws marioright.

The problem is that both images are loaded at the same time, and they also move at the same time. I would like the 2 to move with the right key. What is wrong with my code?

I thought that I should put a condition on the load function, but I do not know how to do that.

What type of condition should I use?
`if ()`, `if else`, `switch` ... and how do I use them?

```js
var vp = document.getElementById("villa_mario");
var paper = vp.getContext("2d");
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveMario);

var x = 250;
var y = 250;

var keys = {
  UP: 38,
  DOWN: 40,
  LEFT: 37,
  RIGHT: 39
};

var background = {
  url: "tile.png",
  loadOK: false
}

var marioright = {
  url: "mario_right.png",
  loadOK: false
}

var marioleft = {
  url: "mario_left.png",
  loadOK: false
}

background.imagen = new Image();
background.imagen.src = background.url;
background.imagen.addEventListener("load", loadBackground);

marioright.imagen = new Image();
marioright.imagen.src = marioright.url;
marioright.imagen.addEventListener("load", loadMarioright);

marioleft.imagen = new Image();
marioleft.imagen.src = marioleft.url;
marioleft.imagen.addEventListener("load", loadMarioleft);


function loadBackground()
{
  background.loadOK = true
  paint();
}

function loadMarioright()
{
  marioright.loadOK = true
  paint();
}

function loadMarioleft()
{
  marioleft.loadOK = true
  paint();
}



function paint()
{
   if(background.loadOK)
   {
    paper.drawImage(background.imagen, 0, 0);
   }

   if(marioright.loadOK)
    {
      paper.drawImage(marioright.imagen, x, y);
    }

    if(marioleft.loadOK)
    {
      paper.drawImage(marioleft.imagen, x, y);
    }
}

function moveMario(evento)
{
  var movement = 5;
  switch(evento.keyCode)
  {
    case keys.RIGHT:
    loadMarioright(x, y, x + movement, y, paper);
    x = x + movement;
    break;
    case keys.LEFT:
    loadMarioleft(x, y, x - movement, y, paper);
    x = x - movement;
    break;
    default:
      console.log("other key");
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Villa Mario</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="villa_mario" width="500" height="500">
    </canvas>
    <script src="mario.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set false to 'loadOk' variable.
Update the loadMarioright(),loadMarioleft() functions as follows.

```
function loadMarioright()
{
  marioright.loadOK = true;
  marioleft.loadOK = false;
  paint();
}

function loadMarioleft()
{
  marioleft.loadOK = true;
  marioright.loadOK = false;
  paint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ragu bathi is right in that you need to toggle loadOK off in order to make it load correctly, but I would suggest removing the extra complication of having toggles on every image by forcing it to only draw one Mario every time you paint. The way you control it this time is by just selecting which image you want to use.

```
var marioToDraw = marioright;

function paint() {
    if(background.loadOK) {
        paper.drawImage(background.imagen, 0, 0);
    }

    //draw the selected Mario
    paper.drawImage(marioToDraw.imagen, x, y);

}

//inside the switch statement
switch(evento.keyCode) {
    case keys.RIGHT:  
        marioToDraw = marioright;
        x = x + movement;
        break;
    case keys.LEFT:
        marioToDraw = marioleft;
        x = x - movement;
        break;
    default:
      console.log("A different key was pressed!");
}
paint();
```